# How to prevent log4j (version 1.2.14) AyncAppender from logging unnecessary text

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm trying to use log4j with an AsyncAppender in my application. See below:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">

    <appender name="asyncAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
        <param name="BufferSize" value="500"/>
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
    </appender>

    <!-- file appender -->
    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="C:/IFFC-Home/logs/iffcserver.log" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5MB" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Thread Message -->
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}] [%t] [%-5p] %c: %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- console appender -->
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message -->
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}] [%t] [%-5p] %c: %m%n"/>
         </layout>
     </appender>

     <category name="com.oberon">
         <priority value="TRACE"/>
     </category>

     <root>
         <priority value="INFO"/>
         <appender-ref ref="asyncAppender"/>
     </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

The application spins off another thread to do the log monitoring for the application.

After deploying my application to Wildfly 8.1 and starting it, I do see my logs get logged both in the console window and in the log file BUT I end up with a ton of these messages:

```
[2014-10-22 17:00:36,966] [AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-85] [INFO ] stdout: [2014-10-22 17:00:36,820] [AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-85] [INFO ] stdout: [2014-10-22 17:00:36,719] [AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-85] [INFO ] stdout: [2014-10-22 17:00:36,694] [AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-85] [INFO ] stdout: [2014-10-22 17:00:36,671] [AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-85] [INFO ] stdout: [2014-10-22 17:00:36,649] [AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-85] [INFO ] stdout: [2014-10-22 17:00:36,625] [AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-85] [INFO ] stdout: [2014-10-22 17:00:36,599] [AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-85] [INFO ] stdout:
```

It's all in one line and it's just the same thing repeated over and over. This only happens if I try using the AsyncAppender.

I also turned on log4j debug and this is what it prints out in the Wildfly server log:

```
2014-10-22 17:00:36,266 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: reset attribute= "false".
2014-10-22 17:00:36,267 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Threshold ="null".
2014-10-22 17:00:36,269 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
2014-10-22 17:00:36,270 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Setting [com.oberon] additivity to [true].
2014-10-22 17:00:36,273 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Level value for com.oberon is  [TRACE].
2014-10-22 17:00:36,274 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: com.oberon level set to TRACE
2014-10-22 17:00:36,275 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Level value for root is  [INFO].
2014-10-22 17:00:36,276 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: root level set to INFO
2014-10-22 17:00:36,277 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender]
2014-10-22 17:00:36,286 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Setting property [bufferSize] to [500].
2014-10-22 17:00:36,287 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Attaching appender named [consoleAppender] to appender named [asyncAppender].
2014-10-22 17:00:36,288 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
2014-10-22 17:00:36,290 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
2014-10-22 17:00:36,294 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [[%d{ISO8601}] [%t] [%-5p] %c: %m%n].
2014-10-22 17:00:36,296 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Attaching appender named [fileAppender] to appender named [asyncAppender].
2014-10-22 17:00:36,297 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender]
2014-10-22 17:00:36,300 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:/IFFC-Home/logs/iffcserver.log].
2014-10-22 17:00:36,301 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [5].
2014-10-22 17:00:36,301 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [5MB].
2014-10-22 17:00:36,302 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
2014-10-22 17:00:36,302 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [[%d{ISO8601}] [%t] [%-5p] %c: %m%n].
2014-10-22 17:00:36,303 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: setFile called: C:/IFFC-Home/logs/iffcserver.log, true
2014-10-22 17:00:36,304 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: setFile ended
2014-10-22 17:00:36,305 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-84) log4j: Adding appender named [asyncAppender] to category [].
```

Is there something I'm missing to correctly configure this and remove all those extra repeated messages?

Answer (score 0):

I have learned that Wildfly 8.1 [implicitly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments#Implicitmoduledependenciesfordeployments-ImplicitmoduledependenciesfordeploymentsWhicha...) adds logging API dependencies to your deployments. In my case, not only did my app have it's own logging being initialized but also Wildfly's.

To only have your applications logging, you must exclude Wildfly's logging subsystem from you application deployment. This can be done in the [jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly#ClassLoadinginWildFly-JBossDeploymentStructureFile) file, which would be in the META-INF directory for an ear, like below:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- exclude-subsystem prevents a subsystems deployment unit processors running on a deployment -->
        <!-- which gives basically the same effect as removing the subsystem, but it only affects single deployment -->
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I was able to piece together this from [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIusemyownversionoflog4j%3F).

However, this still didn't fix my issue with AsyncAppender and so I've opted to go the route of [per-deployment-logging in Wildfly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-PerdeploymentLogging). This is what it says on the site:

Per-deployment logging allows you to add a logging configuration file to your deployment and have the logging for that deployment configured according to the configuration file. In an EAR the configuration should be in the META-INF directory. In a WAR or JAR deployment the configuration file can be in either the META-INF or WEB-INF directories.

The following configuration files are allowed:

```
logging.properties
jboss-logging.properties
log4j.properties
log4j.xml
jboss-log4j.xml
```

After disabling the logging being initialized in my app and applied the per-deployment-logging configurations I was able to use AsyncAppender with no issues. The tradeoff is now my application is not as portable but this works for now.

This is a good resource too: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-log/using-log4j-with-jboss-as-7-and-wildfly